# Keeper Clickhouse Replication DDL on cluster, but no replication data, error "Table was in readonly mode"

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

In the test, the Keeper process replicates the DDL in the cluster, but a table of type ReplicatedMergeTree, it creates it in all the nodes, but when I insert information into the table, the data only in the node where the insertion is executed, in the Other nodes, these do not have data insertion executed.

The configuration remote server's

```
<remote_servers replace="true">
        <clustertest>
            <secret>key</secret>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>nod1</host>
                    <port>3307</port>
                </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>nod2</host>
                    <port>3307</port>
                </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>nod3</host>
                    <port>3307</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </cluster_gbit>
    </remote_servers>
```

The macros

```
<macros>
        <shard>1</shard>
        <replica>01</replica>
        <cluster>clustertest</cluster>
    </macros>
```

The keeper

```
<keeper_server>
            <tcp_port>19181</tcp_port>
            <server_id>1</server_id>
            <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/logs</log_storage_path>
            <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>

            <coordination_settings>
                <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
                <min_session_timeout_ms>10000</min_session_timeout_ms>
                <session_timeout_ms>100000</session_timeout_ms>
                <raft_logs_level>information</raft_logs_level>
                <compress_logs>false</compress_logs>
            </coordination_settings>

            <hostname_checks_enabled>true</hostname_checks_enabled>
            <raft_configuration>
                <server>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <hostname>nod1</hostname>
                    <port>19234</port>
                </server>
                <server>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <hostname>nod2</hostname>
                    <port>19234</port>
                </server>
                <server>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <hostname>nod3</hostname>
                    <port>19234</port>
                </server>
                <server>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <hostname>keeper</hostname>
                    <port>19234</port>
                </server>
        </raft_configuration>
    </keeper_server>
```

Example the create

```
CREATE TABLE dwhcluster.table1 ON CLUSTER clustertest
(
    `id` UInt64,
    `column1` String
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree
ORDER BY id

INSERT INTO dwhcluster.table1
    (id, column1)
VALUES
    (3, 'abc'),
    (4, 'def')
```

`Error en log the server remote

ERROR : dwhcluster.table1 (ae4d40e3-b7e5-4a70-9268-20dcdcbab970): void DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::mutationsUpdatingTask(): Code: 999. Coordination::Exception: Session expired. (KEEPER_EXCEPTION), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):`

Comment: Wrong cluster config - 3 shards with 1 replica each (this means no replication at all in fact). Do you want 1 shard & 3 replicas config? What are the `default_replica_path` & `default_replica_name` server settings on all servers (you must set them if you don't specify the RMT engine parameters in the `CREATE TABLE` statement)? `</cluster_gbit>` - is this typo?

Comment: Replication only happens where there is more than 1 replica. In your setup, you have 3 shards, each with 1 replica. Please adjust your server topology to have more than 1 replicas per shard so that data in ReplicatedMergeTree created on these replicas will be replicated. Here's the doc on how you can setup multiple replicas per shard - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/architecture/replication#replication-and-sharding-configuration